# Join tables using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting the institutes within 10km in $result. But I want to get the institutes with course name having GATE. How can I do this?
course_records has a foreign key institute_id in institutes. I am not able to join these tables.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
 $result=$conn->query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($user_latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($user_longitude) ) + sin( radians($user_latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM institutes  HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance  LIMIT 0 , 10 ");
```

mysql> select * from  institutes;

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------+
| institute_id | name              | email               | contact_number | address                          | telephone   | tut_id | latitude | longitude |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|           23 | Dhananjay Classes | dhananjay@gmail.com | 9999888877     | Palam dabri Road,Mahavir Enclave | 011-1234567 |     11 |  28.5892 |   77.0858 |
|           24 | ffe               | rr@rere             | 323232         |                                  |             |     11 |  28.5667 |   77.2833 |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

mysql> select * from course_records;

```
+-----------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| course_id | name | subject      | fees  | num_students | num_students_per_teacher | month_of_admission | num_of_trials | commision | created | institute_id |
+-----------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------+
|         1 | GATE | CSE          | 10000 | 110          | 20                       | January            | 3             | yes       | NULL    |           23 |
|         2 | NDA  | all_subjects | 7000  | 50           | 20                       | April              | 3             | yes       | NULL    |           23 |
|         3 | 12th | Math         | 2     | 90           | 20                       |                    | 2             |           | NULL    |           23 |
+-----------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with:

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT
i.name as inst_name, cr.name as course_name,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($user_latitude) ) * cos( radians( i.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( i.longitude ) - radians($user_longitude) ) + sin( radians($user_latitude) ) * sin( radians( i.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM
institutes i
join course_records cr on i.institute_id = cr.institute_id
where cr.name = 'GATE'
HAVING
distance < 10 ORDER BY distance  LIMIT 0 , 10 ");
```

you can add more field from both table as select field by using alias of table like `cr.subject` for course subject from `course_records` table.

Comment: the code worked after adding comma , after 'SELECT
i.name as inst_name, cr.name as course_name'

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how are you calculating the distance and I am not going in its detail. Please crosscheck your formula for it. Assuming that you correct it, try something like this. Here the `latitude` and `longitude` is hardcoded but you can change it back the way you want for `php`. Also the distance I am using is `50`.

```
select * from 
(
        SELECT
        i.*, c.name as course_name,
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(28.5892) ) * cos( radians( i.latitude ) ) 
          * cos( radians( i.longitude ) - radians(77.0858) ) + sin( radians(28.5892) ) 
          * sin( radians( i.latitude ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance
        FROM
        institutes i
        inner join course_records c on i.institute_id = c.institute_id
) as dist
where dist.distance <50
and dist.course_name='GATE'
```

**[View SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a27f/10)**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a27f/10

Answer (score 2):

```
$result=$conn->query("(SELECT institutes.*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($user_latitude) ) * cos( radians( institutes.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( institutes.longitude ) - radians($user_longitude) ) + sin( radians($user_latitude) ) * sin( radians( institutes.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM institutes join on institutes.institute_id=course_records.institute_id) as Table1  HAVING Table1.distance < 10 and Table1.course_name like '%GATE%' ORDER BY Table1.distance  LIMIT 0 , 10 ");
```

Just replace your code with the above,
Hope this works for you.